# SQL dataread to a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am trying yo get the data from database to the text! the code i have pasted works fine and it does not give me any exception but the problem is this it cannot get the required data from the database it fetch `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`.

Kindly help me to sort out the issue...

////CODE////

```
private void ReplaceBookmarkText(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc, string bookmarkName,string text)
{
   object objI=1 ;
   object count = 7;
   object oCount = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdConstants.wdForward;
   object oUnit = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;
   int number;
   //here is your name, store it where ever you want:
   bookmarkName = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Name;
   //bookmarkEnd = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).End;
   //bookmarkStart = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Start;
   number = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Range.MoveEnd(ref oUnit, ref count);
   //bookmarkEnd = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Start;
   string bookmarkValue = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref objI).Range.Text;
   MessageBox.Show(bookmarkValue);
   string db_name = "";

   try
   {
      sql_con = new SqlConnection(con_str);
      sql_con.Open();

      //"SELECT FirstName FROM ContactPerson WHERE (Contact_ID = " + fNameTemp + ")");
      // select s_name from student where s_reg = '11-ARID-4204'
      // string sql_query = ("select s_name from student where (s_reg = " + txtboxrollno + ")");
      //"Select * from logintable where password=" + "'TextBox1.Text'";
      sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
      string qrery = ("select s_name from student where (s_reg = " + "'txtboxrollno.text'" + ")");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qrery,sql_con);
      //sql_cmd.CommandText = ("select s_name from student where (s_reg = " + txtboxrollno.Text.Trim() + ")");
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      MessageBox.Show(cmd.ToString());
      SqlDataReader sdr; 
      sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      //textBox1.Text = sdr.ToString();
      db_name = textBox1.Text;

      while(sdr.Read())
      {
         //textBox1.Text = sdr["s_name"].ToString();
         textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
         //txtpatientid.Text = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
         //fNameTextBox.Text = sdr["FirstName"].ToString();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am confused about what exactly your problem is.  Could you try to clarify in one sentence exactly what the issue is?

Comment: **WARNING**: your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Please research using [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: The problem is this it does not show any data got from database! i want it to show me the data from the database! cmd.ExecuteQuery() should have returned the data instead of System.bla....

Comment: You have: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` in your code which **does not** return anything.  And your `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` will return only one value from one row.

Comment: what `cmd.ExecuteQuery()` should do is irrelevant because that is no where in your code.  You do have `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` in your code, but that will only return the number of rows affected.  You have not helped clarify what your problem is...

Comment: Another thing... this syntax is wrong:  `string qrery = ("select s_name from student where (s_reg = " + "'txtboxrollno.text'" + ")");`.  This should be:  `string qrery = ("select s_name from student where (s_reg = " + txtboxrollno.text + ")");`.

Comment: Why have you posted this code snippet?  Voting to close because you are not putting any effort into this question.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
string qrery = "select s_name from student where (s_reg = @s_reg)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qrery,sql_con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_reg", txtboxrollno.Text);
textBox1.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
```

There are some other things I'm going to recommend. But let's start with that. That will take the first result, of the first row, and put it into the text box.

Comment: Michael its not working man!!!  :(

Comment: @user2509861, that give me no information man!!! What does *not working man!!!* mean?

Comment: Brain, Boss i have tried your recommendations of ExecuteScalar(); but its empty!!!! :(

Comment: @user2509861, if it's empty then that means the query itself isn't returning any data. Put a breakpoint **before** running the query, grab the actual query from the `Watch` window, and run it by hand. What does it return?

Comment: Dear Michael sorry to bother you time and again!but when ran the query again by hand! it returned me again!! system.read.etc

Comment: @user2509861, please see my edit. **NOTE:** if you didn't capitalized `txtboxrollno` property you'll get a build error. You weren't even sending in the value to the query friend, you were sending the literal text `txtboxrollno.text` in the query. That's clearly going to return **zero** rows.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, Brain.... everyone!!! highly appreciate your efforts made to help me! anyways my code works fine with the Michael's logic!!! Thanks every one once again!!!! :))